# can not access local HTTPS site from another PC on Ubuntu 16.4

Tags: ubuntu, apache-virtualhost

I was developing a PWA(Progressive Web Application) on my Ubuntu 16.4 Offline and one requirement of the framework is an HTTPS connection to be able to run.

I configured my Apache server and enabled the HTTPS VirtualHost configuration. But the problem with the configuration is that I can't access it via HTTPS, only HTTP can access the local site. Apparently, the site works well on the development machine on both protocols.

Comment: ... and the error you get is...?

Comment: ... and the steps you took to enable HTTPS were...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have actually had the same problem. I'll be interested to see a solution. I used a workaround and sacrificed encryption when accessed locally. Everything works fine from outside the network though. I edited /etc/hosts to map directly to local ip rather than having the DNS request happen remotely to send me back to my network. 
Example

```
127.0.1.1          hostname
127.0.0.1          localhost
Local.app.ip     www.example.com
```

This doesn't fix anything it's just convenient since otherwise it defaults to https and then won't load.

One of the machines I had this problem on was a laptop which posed a problem if I changed the hosts file and then was outside my local network. It would still try to connect to a local ip. I solved this with a bash script I found online that changes the file based on if a certain wifi network is available. Just for fun here is the script.

```
 
wifi=`iwlist wlp3s0 scan | grep SSID`
if [[ $wifi == *Home-Network* ]]
then
    #Use special host file
    cp -f /home/Documents/hosts.home /etc/hosts
else
    #Use normal host file
    cp -f /home/Documents/hosts.away /etc/hosts
fi
```

EDIT#200
It's stored in  /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d so it runs at startup.